# How to use Angular's $log service from inside my own services/providers?

Tags: angularjs, logging, service

I got error when I injected it in the normal way - so is it possible to use $log inside my own services and/or providers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course.

Are you sure you're injecting it correctly?

```
yourApp.service('myService', ['$log', function ($log) {
    $log.log('Hi console!');
}]);
```

Comment: What about injecting into a factory?

Comment: Services/Factories are all just shorthand for `providers`. In the end they're all basically the same, just a different way of doing the same thing, with `providers` being the most verbose. But yup, It can work with any of them!

Comment: I decided to revert all my changes and try injecting one function at a time, testing after each change. Looks like I can't inject `$log` into `angular.module.config()`.

Comment: Yes you're correct. `.config()` only accepts actual providers like `$locationProvider` etc